# Issue deploying war due to JDK incompatibility

Tags: primefaces, websphere

Facing an issue with deploying a war file in Websphere AS 8.5.5.11 that gives the following error:

> UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version

This is Maven built war file & I have compiled the war with JDK 1.7.0_80 ; the JDK that is used by WAS on that VM is JDK 1.7.1 so I don’t know if there is any incompatibility there. 
One thing I do suspect is one of the dependent libraries - the primefaces6.jar. It was compiled with version 1.8.0 according to it's manifest file.  If that is the reason for the code the application to error then I don't know how to proceed.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: _"If that is the reason for the code the application to error then I don't know how to proceed."_ Download the source and compile with a different version? Trying this is at least an option. And If you encounter compile errors then there will certainly be few. And does the error not state which class it is? Sure it is PF?

Answer (score -1):

WAS 8.x usually runs on a Java 7 JVM. It's not fully clear since IBM hides the Java version, or sometimes even report one, but it's not exactly what you expect.

Anyway, you cannot run a library compiled in Java 8 in a Java 7 JVM. You are outof luck, and should have prevented this to happen in the first place.

Solution? Download another (older) version of your library, that will run in Java 7. You don't have another option. Of course, that old library may have less functionality or may even be buggier, but you got yourself alone into this mess, don't you? :D

Comment: Well - yes it is a bit of a mess. Will need to back out the newer libraries or possibly maintain a separate branch of the code to be backward compatible...and it's a Monday :(

Comment: Use the source Luke... https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use%20the%20Source%2C%20Luke ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje This may be a great solution, albeit non-traditional. Well... as long as the source doesn't have Java 8-specific coding.